# uiscrollview won't cancel content touches for uisegmentedcontrol

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol, touches

I've subclassed th UIScrollView and overriden the touchesShouldCancelInContentView: method the following way:

```
-(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view

{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) {
        return YES;
    }

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

It works perfectly for UIButton, but it doesn't work for UISegmentedControl. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Even if I put only return YES, it still doesn't cancel the touch on the segmented control, like it's purposely made that way, so i guess i'll have to subclass the UISegmentedControl also, and find the way to do it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Had to subclass both UISegmentedControl and UIScrollView.

1.) added a new property for UISegmentedControl:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL touchProcessed;
```

2.) overloaded the following methods of the UISegmentedControl:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (touchProcessed) {
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else {
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    self.touchProcessed = NO;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

3.) overloaded the following methods of th UIScrollview:

```
-(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{ 
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[self class]])
    {
        return YES; //if there are two nested custom scrollviews  
    }

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[CustomSegmentedControl class]] || [[view superview] isKindOfClass:[CustomSegmentedControl class]]) {
        return YES;
    }

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.dragging) {
        for (UIView *sv in self.subviews) {
            if ([sv isKindOfClass:[CustomSegmentedControl class]])
            {   //if there is more than one add a tag or tomething
                [(CustomSegmentedControl *)sv setTouchProcessed:YES];
                [sv touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
                return;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Works perfectly!