# UITableView Scroll with Content Touch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In a `UIViewController`, I am having a `UIView` of 300 height named as `headerView` and inside `UISegmentControl` and below that I have `UITableView`.

My need is I want to scroll `UITableView` no matter what ever content touches, so I have achieved that for `headerView` but when I touch and scroll on `UISegmentControl` it receives action and scrolling doesn't occurs.

How did I manage to scroll when touches `headerView` is via `hitTest`.

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event) {
        if hitView is UISegmentControl {
            return hitView //From here I want action to change the Segment Control but it doesn't scroll
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I have tried with `UITableView` property named `delaysContentTouches` & `canCancelContentTouches` but none of this works. Any idea?

Comment: why you didn't subclass `UISegmentControl`? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342511/uiscrollview-wont-cancel-content-touches-for-uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: Just to get the action via `hitTest` method. The sub classing receives tap action nothing else. I am gonna look at that solution now!